# apt-key is deprecated

Tags: apt, keyrings

i want to remove a repository but every time i get the error "**Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).**"
ive tried updating apt-key and apt-get just to be sure but didnt solve the problem.
please help.

like this command `$ sudo apt-key del 7D8D08F6` .

Answer (score 8):

The answer is in the notice: **Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead**

So

```
cd /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
rm {file}
```

where {file} needs to be replaced by the filename (7D8D08F6?) you want removed.

Comment: Could you please check? This information is probably outdated or [misleading.](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty) I found this [here.](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/01/apt-key-is-deprecated-how-to-add.html) Moritz Bunkus (mkvtoolnix) also updated his repositories with these new instructions, he is usually quick and careful. Using `signed-by=` for each repo makes sense. Cloud-Init still uses apt-key though.

Answer (score 4):

You first need to find the keychain where the key with id `7D8D08F6` is stored:

```
for f in /etc/apt/trusted.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/*.{asc,gpg}; do
  $(gpg --list-keys --keyid-format short --no-default-keyring --keyring $f | fgrep -iq 7D8D08F6) && echo "Key 7D8D08F6 in $f"
done
```

and then delete this keyring:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/<KEYRING>.gpg
```

Comment: Important: User `gpg` with absolute paths as shown in the example. Otherwise keyrings would be searched in your ~/.gnupg directory.