# How do I add repo gpg keys as apt-key is deprecated?

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, repository, gnupg

After one of my recent updates, I noticed that my 3rd party repos were failing to update due to the `NO_PUBKEY` error from apt. I looked for hours to find a fix, but all fixes suggest using apt-key. However, that no longer works because it has been deprecated. So I manually copied one repo's keys from `/usr/share/keyrings` to `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` as a test and that seems to work. Now everything works for that app.

My question is: is there a new function to download keys from a keyserver instead of the `apt-key` function? Most sites have not realized this change and offer the `apt-key` command for their repo keys and that just returns errors now. And how to update my current third party repo keys as only they have the problem? Should I manually `cp` the keys as I mentioned above, or is there a more efficient solution?

EDIT: I am on 20.10. Apt-key works for 20.04 but not after that.

```
$ sudo apt update
Err:9 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release.gpg
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9658E8044A3AA3D6

W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9658E8044A3AA3D6
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9658E8044A3AA3D6
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: What OS & release are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-key is deprecated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287183/apt-key-is-deprecated)

Comment: @guiverc I am on 20.10

Comment: @Artur Meinild I saw that post but it doesn't answer my question as to what tool I should use now instead of apt-key to add repo keys from sites.

Comment: I don't believe you issue is with `apt-key` being relegated, but the keys you're trying to import are EOL & relegated.  Due to md5 being no longer treated as secure, any keys that used md5 were depreciated.  You should provide full command & error message for specific details (*instead of generic*)

Comment: @guiverc hmmm may be, but I fixed this issue by simply moving a key from one place to another as described in my post. If it was an md5sum issue, the key should not work no matter where I place it. Right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Comment: @Kulfy That answer comes close but not really. I am looking for what is the new function, what replaces apt-key for downloading keys from sites as they all give instructions with apt-key which end in errors. Most answers on that post use apt-key and the accepted one uses an app I need to download. It cannot be that I must install software to get repo keys in the right place.

Comment: @guiverc I added errors for you

Comment: @i9pp0 [Pedram's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/32313/816190) doesn't use apt-key. Neither [htorque's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/13078/816190) does. Though I don't use 20.10 but according to https://manpages.debian.org/testing/apt/apt-key.8.en.html, apt-key should be there till Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: @Kulfy Pedram's answer does use apt-key. htorque's doesn't but it is a long work around that cannot be the only way to add third party repos to my system. Sites give a one liner to add their repo key using apt-key. Apt-key no longer works on 20.10. My question is what is the "new" way to add repo keys? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`apt-key` never downloaded keys by itself. `apt-key adv` passed on options to `gpg`, and `gpg` did the actual downloading (`apt-key` is a [complicated shell script](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/2.0.y/cmdline/apt-key.in) that itself creates temporary scripts to run `gpg`). You can still use `gpg` to import keys, e.g. instead of `apt-key adv --recv-keys`, you'd do something like:

```
sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/foo.gpg --recv-keys 9658E8044A3AA3D6
```

Or instead of `wget ... | apt-key add -`:

```
wget -qO - https://example.com/somekey.gpg |
  sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/example.gpg --import -
```

Notes:

1. GnuPG will create trust stores in root's home directory. Use `--homedir` with some other part if you want to avoid that.
2. GnuPG creates keyrings in the new keybox format by default, and these don't work with `apt`, but using the `gnupg-ring:` prefix makes it uses the old format for some reason.

If your software already had keyrings installed in `/usr/share/keyrings`, then presumably their `sources.list` entries should have had something like `[signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/foo.gpg]` (cf. [the Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty#Sources.list_entry)).

Comment: does apt walk through all keyrings in /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ ?

Comment: it doesn't work with webmin