# Help installing package?

Tags: apt

I asked [this question](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/4688/difficulty-installing-stellar-quickstart-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts) so most of the details are there. But, to sum up: I've added a PPA (maybe it isn't technically a PPA but it acts as such) to my sources.list.d directory and run `sudo apt-get update`
For some reason though, I still can't get my system to find the package.
Would greatly appreciate any help.

```
$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
```

```
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
```

```
$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for ramy: 
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                            
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                                                                                   
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]                                                                                                
Hit:5 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com focal InRelease                                                                                                                    
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/forkotov02/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:7 https://apt.stellar.org focal InRelease                       
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [274 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [24.4 kB]        
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [323 kB]                      
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [58.3 kB]                 
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]                                       
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1,768 B]
Get:15 https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/deb/ubuntu focal InRelease [5,054 B]          
Fetched 1,020 kB in 1s (772 kB/s)                                     
Reading package lists... Done
```

To install the package I followed [this guide](https://github.com/stellar/packages/blob/master/docs/adding-the-sdf-stable-repository-to-your-system.md). It instructs me to run do two things. First
[Download and install the public signing key](https://github.com/stellar/packages/blob/master/docs/adding-the-sdf-stable-repository-to-your-system.md#download-and-install-the-public-signing-key) with

```
wget -qO - https://apt.stellar.org/SDF.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

and [Save the repository definition to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/SDF.list] [4](https://github.com/stellar/packages/blob/master/docs/adding-the-sdf-stable-repository-to-your-system.md#save-the-repository-definition-to-etcaptsourceslistdsdflist) with echo "deb https://apt.stellar.org $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/SDF.list

```
echo "deb https://apt.stellar.org $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/SDF.list
```

The two commands above show the following output:

```
:~$ wget -qO - https://apt.stellar.org/SDF.asc | sudo apt-key add -
OK
:~$ echo "deb https://apt.stellar.org $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/SDF.list
deb https://apt.stellar.org focal stable
```

Comment: Your question should *exactly* what you added instead of the current vague description. Also, your question should include the complete output of `sudo apt update` and the complete input and output of your attempt to install the missing package.

Comment: Please also include the outputs of `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` to help us to understand why you got the `doesn't support architecture 'i386'` message

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my question. I'm not sure I completely capture `the complete input and output of your attempt to install the missing package` but hopefully this is enough to go on.

Comment: I am not sure why it isn't finding it, but you could download the .deb directly and install it with gdebi https://apt.stellar.org/pool/stable/s/stellar-quickstart/

Comment: Sorry misread your comment. This worked like a charm! If you want to add this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add repo gpg keys as apt-key is deprecated?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295102/how-do-i-add-repo-gpg-keys-as-apt-key-is-deprecated)

Comment: Hi `add apt-key` is deprecated, I have marked your question as duplicate.

Comment: Not sure if it does answer my question. Can you help me understand what should go in place of `example.gpg` in the question/answer you linked to? I'm trying to test the answer now.