# how to replace apt-key for webmin

Tags: 20.04, bash, gnupg, add-apt-repository, webmin

how to replace apt-key for webmin in ubuntu 20.04 (because apparently `apt-key` [is deprecated](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/01/apt-key-is-deprecated-how-to-add.html))?

before (bash script):

```
wget -q https://www.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib"
sudo apt install webmin
```

now error:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found
```

I tried [with this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1295145/828892), but it doesn't work (bash script):

```
wget -qO - https://www.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc | sudo gpg --dearmor | sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/webmin.gpg --import -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib"
sudo apt install webmin
```

Note: with or without `sudo gpg --dearmor` or `http/https`

new error:

```
GPG error: http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge Release: The following signatures could not be verified because their public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D97A3AE911F63C51
```

how do i fix it (bash script)? thanks

Comment: hi, can you please tell us which Ubuntu version you're using ?

Comment: in the question above is the SO and the version. ubuntu 20.04 x64

Comment: yeah my bad i didn't notice that sorry

Comment: don't worry. it has happened to me too

Comment: Have you tried to install http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.981_all.deb ?

Comment: when running `sudo apt update` do you get error : The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D97A3AE911F63C51 ?

Comment: @WaLidLamRaoui yes. this is it. (the error described appears in the question)

Comment: @N0rbert I can't be downloading the .deb every time webmin is updated. That's what the repository is supposed to be for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason the key wasn't imported correctly, you can always check  by listing all currently imported keys by executing :

```
apt-key list
```

And searching for  `1719 003A CE3E 5A41 E2DE  70DF D97A 3AE9 11F6 3C51`

If it's missing try importing the key from ubuntu keyserver by running :

```
    sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D97A3AE911F63C51
```

the output sould be something like :

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.neTpxcHlMl/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D97A3AE911F63C51
gpg: key D97A3AE911F63C51: public key ..... imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

Again Check if it's imported correctly `apt-key list`.

Finally :

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install webmin
```

this should work.

Comment: why don't you complete the solution including the corrected commands that I posted, because as it is it does not work in a bash script

Comment: did this worked ?

Comment: in your case i think this:  `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D97A3AE911F63C51` with `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install webmin` should get webmin to be installed

Comment: Yes of course. my commands can all be discarded. Just yours is enough. Thank you so much. great contribution

Comment: You're welcome, later i will make an edit to this answer to make it better and even include a bash script to install webmin, but for now it's 1:00 am and i really need to get some rest